# I let you become super, It is not permanent though

Tags: word

> I let you become super,
> It is not permanent though.
> If you remove a home,
> You won't need to preserve.

Hints:

> --

> no

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> the `su` command

which can

> make you the superuser, and even give you the permission to remove the home directory.

Comment: Not quite, but very close!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hints, and Wallbreaker5th’s answer, it seems like it might be

> `sudo rm ~ --no-preserve-root`.

Explanation:

> ‘I let you become super, It is not permanent though.’ ⤳ `sudo` does exactly this.

> ‘If you remove a home,’ ⤳ `rm ~` removes home.

> ‘You won't need to preserve.’ ⤳ `--no-preserve-root`, the start of which is in the hints.

> `sudo rm ~ --no-preserve-root` is a somewhat odd command. Perhaps the answer is the more common `sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root`?

Comment: Also very, very close. The answer is within your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I let you become super,
> It is not permanent though.
> If you remove a home,
> You won't need to preserve.

Answer:

> sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /

I let you become super,
It is not permanent though.

> sudo does this very thing

If you remove a home,
You won't need to preserve.

> the "--no" hint combined with "preserve" is referring to "--no-preserve-root", which overrides the rm default behavior of treating "/" specially with regard to recursion (the "-r").
>  If you use rm with these flags you'll delete all files below /, which is to say all files in the file system.

Comment: Also very, very close. The answer is in your answer.